# Python Dictionary of States

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am writing a program that uses a dictionary of 50 states. This program. will ask users about 8 questions and after the user answer the questions, it will out some thing like 'based on your answer, you should live in this state'. it is a randomized output of state. The questions will loop around until the user decided to stop. This is what I have thus far. Can you help? Thank you

```
 import random
 def main():
        states = {

         'Alabama','Alaska','Arizona','Arkansas','California','Colorado',
         'Connecticut','Delaware','Florida','Georgia','Hawaii','Idaho', 
         'Illinois','Indiana','Iowa','Kansas','Kentucky','Louisiana',
         'Maine' 'Maryland','Massachusetts','Michigan','Minnesota',
         'Mississippi', 'Missouri','Montana','Nebraska','Nevada',
         'New Hampshire','New Jersey','New Mexico','New York',
         'North Carolina','North Dakota','Ohio',    
         'Oklahoma','Oregon','Pennsylvania','Rhode Island',
         'South  Carolina','South Dakota','Tennessee','Texas','Utah',
         'Vermont','Virginia','Washington','West Virginia',
         'Wisconsin','Wyoming'
    }


   print('What city are you from')
   city = input()
   print('What is your favorite team?')
   team = input()
   print('What state is close to you?')
   state = input()
   print('What is the name of your Governor?')
   governor = input()
   print('What is the name of your Senator?')
   senator = input()
   print('what is the name of your Sherif?')
   sherif = input()
   print('What is your favorite baseball team?')
   baseball = input()
   print('What is your favorite basketball team?')
   basketball = input()
   print('What is your favorite hockey team?')
   hockey = input()

   print ('Base on your answer the state you should live in is:' + states)
```

Comment: That's a set, try `type(states)`

Comment: Precisely how or where are you stuck? Where do you need help? Are you looking for a pair-programming partner?

Comment: i have got this one working. As far as your third question, i do need a programming partner. I really want to know this python from a -z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the states you provide is not a dictionary but a set. Try:

```
type(states)
```

For having a random choice. First convert if to a list and then choose as below.

```
import random
states_list = list(states)
choice = random.choice(states_list)
```

So in final line include

```
 print ('Base on your answer the state you should live in is: ' + choice)
```

Comment: you said the state I provided is not a dictionary. What I'm I missing?

Comment: dict is in the form of key values/pairs. like { 1: 'alabama'} but for your purpose why you need a dictionary. You can have a random choice from list.

Comment: how can i convert that to a dictionary and not a set?

Comment: same question why you need a dictionary, because it's just names of states you can only build a set, list, tuple with them. for making a dictionary you would need some keys, like `{ 1: 'alabama', 2: 'Alaska', 3:'Arizona'...` which is unnecessary here.